# How to recover from ENFILE in acceptor loop

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have written a test to show a problem with asio async_accept
I have a server that leave any connection to it open forever
after accepting many connections (in my case 1017) the next
connect fails with "Too many open files" error.
and then any call to async_accept invokes the handler imediately

Is this a misunderstanding?

I use debian 7 amd64

**Makefile**

```
CXX=clang++ -O2
OBJ= main.o server.o
LIBS=-lboost_system -lboost_thread
all: server

server: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o server $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp

server.o: server.hpp server.cpp
    $(CXX) -c server.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~

distclean: clean
    rm -f server
```

**server.hpp**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class server
{
    public:
        server();

        void run();

    private:
        void start_accept();

        void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e);

        boost::asio::io_service ios;

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

        std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket*> sockets;
};
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "server.hpp"

server::server(): acceptor_(ios)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("0.0.0.0", "5050");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
    acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor_.listen();

    start_accept();
}

void server::run()
{
    ios.run();
}

void server::start_accept()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=new  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
    sockets.push_back(s);
    acceptor_.async_accept(*s,
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    if(e)
    {
        std::cerr<<"e.message() = "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=sockets.back();
        s->close();
        delete s;
        sockets.pop_back();
    }
    static int i=1;
    std::cerr<<"i = "<<i++<<std::endl;
    start_accept();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "server.hpp"

int main()
{
    server s;
    s.run();
    return 0;
}
```

and my test is

```
for x in `seq $1`;do nc 127.0.0.1 5050 & done
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please?

Comment: please compile the code, run the server and then create a few thousands(you must create many connections to exceed the limit of process open files(`ulimit -n`)) of parallel connections to the server(port 5050). you can create connections with `nc` . then the program falls into an infinite loop ("Too many open files" error). in this state without creating any new connection, handle_accept is called continually. I want to know if this is a bug in my program or a bug in ASIO or something else?

Comment: Just for clarity: I have been assuming that your real code sometimes closes a connection and removes its socket from the `sockets` container. Otherwise you'd be noticing the obvious resource leak, and I don't think that was the topic of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `server::handle_accept` you submit the asynchronous accept back onto the IO service queue, even though the socket is in error.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but I can make it "work" (recover) by starting the listener fresh on accept failure. (Note that this would require some synchronization if you run the service on multiple threads).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d12378dad111af)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class server
{
    public:
        server();

        void run();

    private:
        bool start_listen();
        void start_accept();
        void handle_accept(boost::system::error_code e);

        boost::asio::io_service ios;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
        std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket*> sockets;
};

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

server::server(): acceptor_(ios)
{
    start_listen();
    start_accept();
}

void server::run()
{
    ios.run();
}

bool server::start_listen()
{
    boost::system::error_code e;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint { {}, 5050 };
    acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor_.bind(endpoint, e);
    if (e)
        return false;
    acceptor_.listen();
    return true;
}

void server::start_accept()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=new  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
    sockets.push_back(s);
    acceptor_.async_accept(*s, boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

#include <iostream>

void server::handle_accept(boost::system::error_code e)
{
    if(e)
    {
        std::cerr<<"e.message() = "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=sockets.back();
        s->close();
        delete s;
        sockets.pop_back();

        acceptor_.close();
        if (!start_listen())
            return;
    }
    static int i=1;
    std::cerr<<"i = "<<i++<<std::endl;
    start_accept();
}

int main()
{
    server s;
    s.run();
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works. but I'm wondering if there is a better solution than closing the acceptor. it is not so safe to close the acceptor, another program may bind to the port. apparently closing the acceptor causes the pending connection to receive a Rst signal. but why the Rst signal is not sent when the async_accept fails. Or if this behavior of Asio is valid is there any other way to Rst the pending connection without closing the acceptor.

Comment: You want to disable the backlog? Otherwise, just add a little yield/delay after a failed accept so you don't hog CPU resources while waiting for a socket to become available

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html for background

Comment: I want a way to reject the new connections when the server can not serve them due to the "Too many open files" error, without closing the acceptor. Or if my design is incorrect I want to know what is my mistake.

Comment: I can't tell whether your design is correct ([see my assumption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146721/how-to-recover-from-enfile-in-acceptor-loop/28148252?noredirect=1#comment44673118_28146721)). And from what I've been reading what you want is simply impossible unless you close the listening socket. Of course, after the backlog gets saturated, any new incoming connection _is already rejected_. So you could just "accept" (sorry for unintended pun) that there are a platform dependent number of accepts in backlog, and avoid hogging the CPU in the accept-loop (by inserting a yield etc.)

Answer (score 0):

When you open the socket this way

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=new  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
```

the socket is not opened, just an object is created. When you try to accept it, you hit the open file decriptor limit, so you get "too many open files" error. Then you just remove it from vector, and create another socket that will not be able to be opened in accept. I think that's the reason of an error.

Update: 
By the way, this function

```
void server::start_accept()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=new  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
    sockets.push_back(s);
    acceptor_.async_accept(*s,
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

seems to have a possible memory leak, if exception is generated in `push_back` method, `s` will be lost.

Update: the inifinte loop is fixed if you rewrite handle_accept this way:

```
void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    if(e)
    {
      auto size = 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cerr<<"e.message() = "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *s=sockets.back();
        s->close();
        delete s;
        sockets.pop_back();
      }
    }
    static int i=1;
    std::cerr<<"i = "<<i++<<std::endl;
    start_accept();
}
```

Comment: he removes it and deletes the socket object. The new one is correctly created in order to be to pass it into `async_accept`. Besides the non-thread-awareness and the lack of exception safety you noted, I don't see how this explains the problem, let alone how to fix it

Comment: @sehe if I understood it correctly, he hits the open file limit in the system. The last socket that the code creates exceeds the limit. Then he removes it and creates another socket, that also exceeds the limit. The socket is created without errors, cause this constructor doesn't open it, it will be set in accept. His question was what is going on here, wasn't it?

Comment: Fair enough. It doesn't, however, explain why there's an infinite loop (there really is. Try with `ulimit -n 10; ./test&` and then ~3 connections)

Comment: @sehe I tried it, I still think that the infinite loop is caused by file limit only. If  you modify the code to remove 2 file decriptors on error, inifnite loop problem goes away. So it's not necessary to restart acceptor this way. See my update.

Comment: Actually, I think the OP wants the connections just to be rejected (so the real answer would involve `backlog` and setting it to 0?)

Comment: @sehe AFAIK at least on linux `backlog` option can be ignored by system under some circumstances, so maybe it not the best way to do it...

Comment: In that case, do the "I'll wait for resources to become available". If you can't yield (because everything is on a single thread, as it appears now), consider inserting a little `async_wait` on a `deadline_timer` so avoid CPU hoggin.